# Why is a Google Drive curl request typically experience much faster upload speeds than a Google Chrome drag-and-drop upload?

Tags: curl, google-api, google-drive-api

I recently have been playing around with Google Drive `curl` based uploads of various files and have noticed that it is much faster, sometimes up to 5x faster, in uploading files than the browser drag-and-drop method.

For example, I ran some tests on a Gigabit connection and found that using `curl` to upload to google drive peaks at around 500 Mbits/sec, while uploading via the Chrome browser peaks around 100 Mbits/sec, even after shutting down extensions, extra tabs, etc.

Does Google Drive give priority to `curl` requests or is there something going on here? My impression is that uploading via browser shouldn't be too much slower as the backend is doing exactly a `curl` request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Google Drive give priority to curl requests or is there something going on here?

First off i dont think anyone on stack can answer that question.  But i will say how do oyu think Google can detect this?

> My impression is that uploading via browser shouldn't be too much slower as the backend is doing exactly a curl request.

- Has it occurred to you that it may be something in the browser that its slow? or throttling the uploads?
- It could be what ever code you are using is not optimized to the best it could be.